# getBounds returning height & width 0

Tags: android, image

```
    photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    photo.setImageBitmap(pic);      
    Drawable drawable = photo.getDrawable();
    imageBounds = drawable.getBounds();
    int scaledHeight = imageBounds.height();
    int scaledWidth = imageBounds.width();
```

Here scaledHeight & scaledWidth are zero. But i am getting the size of image correctly.

```
    int intrinsicHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    int intrinsicWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
```

What is the problem imageBounds.height();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you use "photo" in the onCreate method. There, the ImageView dimensions are not still defined and I suggest you to put your code in the onWindowFocusChanged method, when "hasFocus" is true.

Comment: thanks @Zappescu. this is working fine. but i was expecting scaledHeight to be the actual height of image displayed on screen, which will be always less than the screen height(for me 320px). but it was same as intrinsicHeight, ie the actual size of image. i tried imageBounds.left also. but it also returned the actual size of image.